# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory yet file directory and everything exists (ruby project)

Tags: ruby, centos7

Error: The application encountered the following error: libicudata.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.6/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so (LoadError)

yet vi /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.6/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so opens it right up...

I am on centos 7 using ruby 2.3.1

Any idea why this is doing this

Comment: Looks like you have to rebuild that gem as the shared library went missing or can't be loaded. You shouldn't be able to `vi` a shared library, it's binary data. Uninstall the gem, and reinstall it.

Comment: Just did that and same result.   When I open it with VI it is all gibberish, and does appear to be compiled.

Comment: `.so` should be shared library, so the idea is those are compiled extensions. Those can break during OS updates, so the best recovery method is to just uninstall and reinstall which forces recompilation.

Comment: I am on my fourth install, and it still doesn't work.  Any other suggestions about what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on another CentOS install? Or with another gem?

Comment: No, I can't i have it working on a centos 6 server, all the same code everything.   The server configurations are nearly identical.